# How can show an image of bytes converted to Json using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json, image, byte

i have my backend to return an List as an list of images.How can show them in other side using Angular. My current code

backend:

```
    public ActionResult RenderingPDF(string fileId)
    {
        return Json(RenderingPDF(fileId), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    public List<byte[]> RenderingPDF(string fileId)
    { .. }
```

and in my JS i have 
`<img ng-repeat="photo in PDFImages track by $index" ng-src="data:image/JPEG;base64,{{photo}}" />`

but this doesn't work.

The http call:

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: options.read + 'RenderingPDF',
    params: {fileId: $scope.selectedFile.FileId}
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    $scope.PDFImages = response.data;
}, function errorCallback(response) {
    $scope.PDFImages = false;
    $scope.PDFImagesErrorResponse = response.data.ExceptionMessage;
});
```

Comment: What does photo contain?

Answer (score 0):

i found solution...

```
$scope.arrayBufferToBase64 = function (buffer) {
        var binary = '';
        var bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
        var len = bytes.byteLength;
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
        }
        return window.btoa(binary);
    }
```

and in html

```
<img ng-src="data:image/JPEG;base64,{{arrayBufferToBase64(photo)}}"/>
```